# Copying attributes from large number of raster files in ArcGIS to Excel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, excel

I am new to GIS, I am having large number of raster files(800) in ArcGis and I want to copy the attribute table of each raster file separately to Excel. Can anyone help me how to perform it in batch mode or using coding?

Comment: Have you succeeded in doing the conversion for one file yet?  I think that is always the best first step to automating a process.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yeah manually i can copy attributes to excel. As i can use Table to excel tool for copying attributes of .shp files to excel. But i am looking for same kind of tool for raster files.

Comment: There's an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it to be just how to convert a raster file's attributes to Excel. What type of raster file do you have?

Comment: I am having raster files (MODIS data) with extension *.tif

Comment: only categorical raster can have an attribute table, so it would be possible with, e.g. MO10A2 snow products, but not with the MOD09 surface reflectance product. Please update your question with more details.

Comment: To compliment @radouxju, another way of saying what he just said is ONLY integer rasters have attribute tables. If your raster is FLOAT or DOUBLE then the attribute table does not exist.

Comment: have you tried this?: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/84698

Comment: I am working with MODIS Snow cover Products (MOD10A2)

Comment: @Hornbydd, Thanks for the link, I will try the code in the link shared, and let you know how it work.

Comment: @Hornbydd, the code shared in the link runs fine and generates .csv files for each raster with header information only. I can't find why the code don't generate all the attributes.I want to add that my raster files are of the type of unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer i got after discussing my problem on geonet.esri.com (link shared in comments by @Hornbydd):
The link to the code is 
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/84698